# Reseting multiple dynamically created Labels

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a piece of code that receives a root element and a dictionary (of a variable size) and using this dictionary it creates rows of 2 labels of *key, value* pairs of the dictionary.

The code does work, but when I call the function with different dictionaries, it puts the labels on top of the old ones which makes it look bad and does not delete spare rows (e.g. I had 10 rows in the last dictionary, and in the current one I have only 5).

I've tried somehow to put it in lists in order to destroy the labels in the beginning of the method, but it does not work.

My try:

```
def dict_to_frame(self, root, dic):
    if self.labels_col_list is not None:
        for i, value in enumerate(self.labels_col_list):
            if value is not None:
                value.destroy()
                self.labels_val_list[i].destroy()
    curr_row = 3
    str_var_col_list = []
    str_var_val_list = []
    self.labels_col_list = []
    self.labels_val_list = []

    for col, val in dic.iteritems():
        if val is None:
            val = "Empty"
        s1 = StringVar()
        s1.set(col+": ")
        str_var_col_list.append(s1)
        s2 = StringVar()
        s2.set(val)
        str_var_val_list.append(s2)

        self.labels_col_list.append(None)
        self.labels_val_list.append(None)
    for i, value in enumerate(str_var_col_list):
        self.labels_col_list[i] = Label(root, textvariable=value).grid(column=1, row=curr_row, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.labels_val_list[i] = Label(root, textvariable=str_var_val_list[i]).grid(column=2, row=curr_row, padx=5, pady=5)
        curr_row += 1
```

How do I solve it? And is there a better way to create the dynamic labels than this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute simplest solution is to put the labels in a frame designed to hold only these labels. You can destroy the frame and it will destroy all the labels for you. Also, if this is static data there's no reason to use `StringVar`s.

Comment: Indeed a simple solution that works great :) Thank you!